# Is Hinduism a religion?

Tags: history, india

There are number of religions present today in the world. Every religion has its Holy book except Hinduism E.g Bible, Quran etc. So which is Holy book of Hinduism?

Also some people says that Hinduism is not a religion, it's a spell of living. Some people like Subramannyam Swami ( BJP party) say that Hinduism is the basis of all religions present in the world. So my question is  Hinduism really a religion or anything else?

Comment: why can't religion be a spell of living? does having holy book only qualifies it to a religion?

Comment: @Whispering I didn't mean to say that but I think if  religion has not a written holy book, for every doctrine the different followers will take it's different meaning .